# How to add Navigation Bar in github jekyll theme

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, navigationbar

I am having hard time adding navbar to the github page.
I downloaded Monophase jekyll theme via this link :
http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/monophase/

I saw a navbar in the demo, but when i applied to the github.io page, I am missing navbar.

Index.markdown:

```markdown
---
layout: default
---
```

If I set layout to default, nothing shows up and if I set to home all the posts are displaying but it does not navbar.
And there is no such thing as _data/navigation.yml in the monophase package zip I downloaded.

_site is set to .gitignore from what I received so I did not include the _site folder to the git as it was originally set, but **do I need to add _site to git and create _data and navigation.yml inside this folder? to make the navigation bar?**

I tried doing this but it did not work out so I'm not sure if I'm doing things right but would be nice if someone can explain what I'm doing wrong ;~;

default.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ page.lang | default: site.lang | default: 'en' }}">
  {% include head.html %}
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {% include header.html %}
      <div>hello</div>
      <main>{{ content }}</main>

      {% include footer.html %}
    </div>

    {% if page.math %} {% include mathjax.html %} {% endif %} {% if
    jekyll.environment == 'production' and site.google_analytics %} {% include
    google-analytics.html %} {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Header.html :

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="masthead-title">
    <a href="{{ '/' | relative_url }}" title="Home">{{ site.title }}</a>
    <small class="tagline">{{ site.tagline }}</small>
  </div>

  {% if site.data.navigation %}
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
      {% for item in site.data.navigation %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="{{ item.url | relative_url }}" class="{% if page.url == item.url %}current{% endif %}">
            {{ item.title }}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  {% endif %}
</header>
```

Home.html:

```html
---
layout: default
title:home
---

<div class="posts">
  {% assign posts = site.posts %} {% if paginator %} {% assign posts =
  paginator.posts %} {% endif %} {% for post in posts %}
  <div class="post">
    <h2 class="post-title">
      <a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}"> {{ post.title }} </a>
    </h2>

    <time datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" class="post-meta"
      >{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</time
    >

    <p class="post-excerpt">
      {% if post.description %} {{ post.description | strip_html }} {% else %}
      {{ post.excerpt | strip_html }} {% endif %}
    </p>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% if paginator %}
<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
  <a
    class="pagination-item older"
    href="{{ paginator.next_page_path | relative_url }}"
    >Older</a
  >
  {% else %}
  <span class="pagination-item older">Older</span>
  {% endif %} {% if paginator.previous_page %}
  <a
    class="pagination-item newer"
    href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | relative_url }}"
    >Newer</a
  >
  {% else %}
  <span class="pagination-item newer">Newer</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or at least it's possible, but unclear given what you've shared.

1. With Jekyll on your desktop, you are locally *building* an html directory which would be a static version of your site. This is very likely the `_site` folder. If this is what you did (successfully), then the contents of that directory are a complete website; *.html files, etc.. Copy the content of this folder to your Git Pages repo, and they should work as-is. _site is in .gitignore because it is a by-product of your code, and in a sense, a duplicate, just in different format.

The advantage of this route is you can view the built html and iterate on your code more quickly, without taking your site down or testing changes live. More to the point, you can open the _site folder and view index.html or similar in your browser to see how things are working. The Demo for this style wasn't working when I tried to access it, and I wasn't able to find the source code for the default implementation (which DID have a nav bar), to be able to tell you how they set it up.

2. The alternative route is to maintain your Git repo with Jekyll-themed files, and Github will *build* the site for you. Assuming up-to-date versions, this should be the same as what you did on your desktop.

For this route, I'd suggest reading documentation on how to add a menu/navigation to your _config.yml file. This is usually where the navigation is specified, but you can certainly override it or customize a navigation in supporting css files. This is also something that you'll want to consult documentation for.